# How to handle drag start event in vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

I have 10 layout .I want to allow all layouts to drag over the other layout.But when layout is dragging then on the hover of any layout,background should be white so it look like as dragged component can 
have space to drop and layout on which dragged component is going to drop is adjusted just below.

So,I think i need on drag event in vaadin.

Comment: What have you tried so far and did you read the [Vaadin book intro](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.dragndrop.html) regarding drag and drop?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Yes..I read.but found no way to handle dragging event.

Answer (score 0):

I think Vaadin tries to tackle the scenario at a higher level of abstraction. I'm referring to section 11.12.4 "Accepting Drops" in https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.dragndrop.html

Vaadin automatically handles the hovering and visual feedback while dragging the component over a possible drop target. Your code defines the accept criteria for the drop target.

If required you can style the visual "drop hints" yourself, adding CSS styles to the container of the drop target.

Comment: I want three things. First is,when user takes component for dragging,it should look like as it is. means same component as it looked before taking.. Second is,when user drag component and drop over the other then at that position I have to create a div element with white background so that user can see space for dropping component.Third is,after dropping,all the component are adjusted.

Comment: So if you have such specific visual requirements you may have to resort to client-side JavaScript coding yourself (code a widget yourself). I would recommend to re-think whether the requirements are really so specific so that you could stick with the above strategy.